# magento2 call api test with postman : nonce validation error

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api, integration, oauth

After my integration is created and authorized, i'm trying to test the Magento REST API with Postman using the access token but an error related to nonce validation occurred.
Any help please??

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use authorization type: Bearer token and then add your access token

I have a screenshot showing my local working:

[image]